# How to "fadeOut" & "remove" a div in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to give fadeout effect to a div & delete that div(id = "notification"), when an image is clicked.

This is how I'm doing that:

```
<a onclick="$("#notification").fadeOut(300,function() { $("#notification").remove(); });" class="notificationClose "><img src="close.png"/></a>
```

This seems to not be working.
What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: 15 votes for the question and 55 votes for the answer... and it was clearly just a typo... wtf?

Comment: Now is 34 and 110 :). Landed here because I didn't know how to remove a element AFTER it faded out (you may guess: I didn't RTFM).

Comment: regardless of the typo, the question appears in google results and I upvote when I find answers quickly.

Comment: well it doesn't really matter if the question had a typo in it.  I for one searched for it because i wanted to know how to do it.  The question asked what i wanted to ask, and there was a working answer.  Therefore upvotes.

Answer (score 487, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a onclick='$("#notification").fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).remove(); });' class="notificationClose "><img src="close.png"/></a>
```

I think your double quotes around the `onclick` were making it not work. :)

**EDIT**: As pointed out below, inline javascript is evil and you should probably take this out of the `onclick` and move it to jQuery's [`click()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click) event handler. That is how the cool kids are doing it nowadays.

Comment: You shouldn't use JavaScript inline, because it makes it hard to change in a consistent way.

Comment: I don't condone it, I'm just helping the guy out with his problem. Sometimes I preach, I just woke up and I'm not in the "extra mile" mood. Your post does the job, though. :)

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the onclick handler is evil? Is it just because of maintainability or is there a technical reason?

Comment: Is it really worth a separate file every time you want one line of JavaScript on a page?  I think inline has its place.

Answer (score 99):

you really should try to use jQuery in a separate file, not inline.  Here is what you need:

```
<a class="notificationClose "><img src="close.png"/></a>
```

And then this at the bottom of your page in `<script>` tags at the very least or in a external JavaScript file.

```
$(".notificationClose").click(function() {
    $("#notification").fadeOut("normal", function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this but couldn't get it to work. The inline link above did work, and the two are practically identical. Here it is... http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/DBrf5/

Comment: @Andy: first of all you forgot to set the library to jQuery ;) Second, if you use it on your site you also need to wrap it in `$(document).ready(function() {` and `});`. (on jsFiddle it is onload so it does that for you)

Comment: @Nick Berardi, can we do it with page down scroll ?

Answer (score 61):

If you're using it in several different places, you should turn it into a plugin.

```
jQuery.fn.fadeOutAndRemove = function(speed){
    $(this).fadeOut(speed,function(){
        $(this).remove();
    })
}
```

And then:

```
// Somewhere in the program code.
$('div').fadeOutAndRemove('fast');
```

Comment: I was just looking at how to do this, and for my purpose, the "plugin" way is better for me, thanks

Answer (score 37):

Have you tried this?

```
$("#notification").fadeOut(300, function(){ 
    $(this).remove();
});
```

That is, using the current **this** context to target the element in the inner function and not the id. I use this pattern all the time - it should work.

Answer (score 9):

if you are anything like me coming from a google search and looking to remove an html element with cool animation, then this could help you:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var $deleteButton = $('.deleteItem');

    $deleteButton.on('click', function(event) {
    
        event.preventDefault();

        var $button = $(this);

        if(confirm('Are you sure about this ?')) {

            var $item = $button.closest('tr.item');

            $item.addClass('removed-item')

                .one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) {

                    $(this).remove();
            });
        }
      
    });
    
});
```

```css
/**
 * Credit to Sara Soueidan
 * @link https://github.com/SaraSoueidan/creative-list-effects/blob/master/css/styles-3.css
 */

.removed-item {
    animation: removed-item-animation .8s cubic-bezier(.65,-0.02,.72,.29)
}

@keyframes removed-item-animation {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0)
    }

    30% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(50px)
    }

    80% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(-800px)
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-800px)
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes removed-item-animation {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0)
    }

    30% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50px);
        transform: translateX(50px)
    }

    80% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(-800px)
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-800px)
    }
}

@-o-keyframes removed-item-animation {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0)
    }

    30% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(50px)
    }

    80% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(-800px)
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-800px)
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>firstname</th>
        <th>lastname</th>
        <th>@twitter</th>
        <th>action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      
      <tr class="item">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Nour-Eddine</td>
        <td>ECH-CHEBABY</td>
        <th>@__chebaby</th>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger deleteItem">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr class="item">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <th>@johndoe</th>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger deleteItem">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr class="item">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Jane</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <th>@janedoe</th>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger deleteItem">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

.fadeOut('slow', this.remove);

Answer (score -10):

Use

```
.fadeOut(360).delay(400).remove();
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the `remove` method gets called immediately after the `fadeOut`