# How to remove an element slowly with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$target.remove()` can remove the element,but now I want the process to be down with some feel animation,how to do it?

Answer (score 395, accepted):

```
$target.hide('slow');
```

or

```
$target.hide('slow', function(){ $target.remove(); });
```

to run the animation, then remove it from DOM

Comment: The .remove() method very specifically removes the node from the DOM. The .hide() method only changes the display attribute to make is not visible, but still in existence.

Comment: @Envil The poster asked how to remove it slowly. .remove() does it immediately.

Comment: @pixelearth put `$(this).remove()` inside the callback function. That works better than `$target.remove()`

Answer (score 116):

```
target.fadeOut(300, function(){ $(this).remove();});
```

or

```
$('#target_id').fadeOut(300, function(){ $(this).remove();});
```

Duplicate: [How to "fadeOut" & "remove" a div in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553402/jquery-fadeout-remove)

Answer (score 24):

If you need to hide and then remove the element use the remove method inside the callback function of hide method.

This should work

```
$target.hide("slow", function(){ $(this).remove(); })
```

Comment: +1 for having the answer right as the comments above got it. Somehow I like the `$(this)` instead of repeating the `$target` too.

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted after I tried the accepted answer, it looks a lot smoother :)

Answer (score 19):

```
$('#ur_id').slideUp("slow", function() { $('#ur_id').remove();});
```

Answer (score 12):

All the answers are good, but I found they all lacked that professional "polish".

I came up with this, fading out, sliding up, then removing:

```
$target.fadeTo(1000, 0.01, function(){ 
    $(this).slideUp(150, function() {
        $(this).remove(); 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm little late to the party, but for anyone like me that came from a Google search and didn't find the right answer. Don't get me wrong there are good answers here, but not exactly what I was looking for, without further ado, here is what I did:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var $deleteButton = $('.deleteItem');

    $deleteButton.on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var $button = $(this);

      if(confirm('Are you sure about this ?')) {

        var $item = $button.closest('tr.item');

        $item.addClass('removed-item')
        
            .one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) {
          
                $(this).remove();
        });
      }
      
    });
    
});
```

```css
/**
 * Credit to Sara Soueidan
 * @link https://github.com/SaraSoueidan/creative-list-effects/blob/master/css/styles-4.css
 */

.removed-item {
    -webkit-animation: removed-item-animation .6s cubic-bezier(.55,-0.04,.91,.94) forwards;
    -o-animation: removed-item-animation .6s cubic-bezier(.55,-0.04,.91,.94) forwards;
    animation: removed-item-animation .6s cubic-bezier(.55,-0.04,.91,.94) forwards
}

@keyframes removed-item-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1)
    }

    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        -ms-transform: scale(0);
        -o-transform: scale(0);
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes removed-item-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1)
    }

    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0
    }
}

@-o-keyframes removed-item-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1)
    }

    to {
        -o-transform: scale(0);
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
  
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>firstname</th>
        <th>lastname</th>
        <th>@twitter</th>
        <th>action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      
      <tr class="item">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Nour-Eddine</td>
        <td>ECH-CHEBABY</td>
        <th>@__chebaby</th>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger deleteItem">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr class="item">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <th>@johndoe</th>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger deleteItem">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr class="item">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Jane</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <th>@janedoe</th>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger deleteItem">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified Greg's answer to suit my case, and it works. Here it is:

```
$("#note-items").children('.active').hide('slow', function(){ $("#note-items").children('.active').remove(); });
```

Answer (score -4):

You mean like

```
$target.hide('slow')
```

?

Comment: Yes,but I also need to delete it after animation.