# JQuery FadeOut/Remove

Tags: jquery, css

This is a follow on from a post here > [How to "fadeOut" & "remove" a div in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553402/jquery-fadeout-remove/) - but we're two years on and rather than dig that up it makes sense to make a new post.

I've played around with it and this works (inline JQuery)

```
<a onclick='$("#alert_top").fadeOut(300, function(){ $(this).remove(); });' class="alert_topClose">Link</a>
```

removing the div "alert_top". But the inline link is untidy.

Attempting to achieve the same result, this doesn't work (JQuery + link)

```
$(".alert_topClose").click(function(){
    $("#alert_top").fadeOut(300, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

with the link

```
<a class="alert_topClose">Link</a>
```

Any help as to why would be greatly appreciated. I can't see what the problem is.

Comment: You're not appending the link after the jQuery has run? In that case you should use on() (http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of click().

Comment: @Filip Yup, or use `.click()` only if the element is available per Shankar's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are executing the above code in `$(document).ready()` or `$()`. If the element is not available when `jQuery` tries to fetch it, it cannot attach the event handler. Try this

```
$(function(){
  $(".alert_topClose").click(function(){
    $("#alert_top").fadeOut(300, function(){
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
});
```